# Prepared params LIKE statement Not working with SQLSRV

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

I am using SQLSRV 3.0 for PHP and working against a MSSQL2008.

My problem I am having, is that I can't get a LIKE statement in the query to work?

```
$connectionOptions = array( "Database"=>$myDB, "UID"=>$myUser, "PWD"=>$myPass);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $myServer, $connectionOptions);

$params = array(
    "$sID%",
    "$sUser%"
);
$sql = "select * from tbl where col2 LIKE ? or col2 LIKE ?";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params); 

if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
```

The problem is related to the design of the items in the params array, any suggestion?

Regards, Jakim

Comment: Try it this way:
    `$params = array(
        $sID."%",
        $sUser."%"
    );`

Comment: Thanks, it didn't work inside the array - but if I added it outside it works just fine. I feel like an dumbass, that I didn't figure this one out ;)

Comment: Should i post as an answer?

Comment: Yes! Please do, this works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust your code to the following:

```
$sql = "select * from tbl where col2 LIKE ? or col2 LIKE ?";
$params = array($sID."%", $sUser."%");
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col2 like '%' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, ?) + '%' or col2 like '%' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, ?) + '%' ";

$searchTerm = "<<some multibye characters>>";

$searchTerm = iconv('utf-8', 'utf-16le', $searchTerm);

$params = array( array($searchTerm, NULL, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING(SQLSRV_ENC_BINARY)));
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I wanted the example above to be clear, so I removed some other stuff, The fact is that I have other params to the query, and therefore having problem to try your example. The sql statement is easy to understand, but the array that is feeding the query contains several of params? Any suggestion how that may look like?

Comment: Can you use a try catch, and then show me the exception?

Comment: I am not getting any errors, just an empty recordset if I put in any searchterms...works fine as long as the % sign is there by it self.