# Insert chinese characters into sql server with php sqlsrv_prepare

Tags: php, sql-server, utf-8, prepared-statement

Im trying to insert a html code with Chinese characters into SQL Server using php sqlsrv_prepare function, but for an unknown reason it doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
$sqlInsertMail = "INSERT INTO EnvioCorreo2Temp (CorreoRemitente,CorreoDestinatario,ContenidoID,ContenidoMail,
AsuntoMail,CCOMail,Link,Orden,CuentaID,EnviadorCorreoID,TestigoID,Prioridad,EstatusID,FUA,Activo,Fecha_Lanzamiento)
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

$stmtDest = sqlsrv_query($conn, $dest_query);
if($stmtDest){ //This condition is for another query executed before for this "IF" clause
    $cont = 0;
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmtDest,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {

        $param1 = 'emailaccount@email.com'; $param2 = $row['email']; $param3 = 0; $param4 = $cuerpoMail; $param5 = $companyName;
        $param6 = 'emailaccount@email.com'; $param7 = $enclnk; $param8 = 1; $param9 = $CuentaCorreoID['CuentaCorreoID']; 
        $param10 = 1; $param11 = 0; $param12 = mt_rand(1,1000); $param13 = 4; $param14 = $fdate2; $param15 = 1; $param16 = $date;

        $params = array(&$param1, &$param2, &$param3, &$param4, &$param5, &$param6, &$param7, &$param8, &$param9, &$param10, &$param11, &$param12, 
        &$param13, &$param14, &$param15, &$param16);

        try{
            if($stmtPrepared = sqlsrv_prepare($conexion, $sqlInsertMail, $params)){
                try{
                    sqlsrv_execute($stmtPrepared);
                }catch (Exception $e) {
                    $bandera = false;
                }

            }
        }catch (Exception $e) {
            $bandera = false;
        }
    }
}else{
    if( ($errors = sqlsrv_errors() ) != null) {
        $bandera = false;
    }
}
```

This code tries to insert a variable with text like this:

```
如果您对本次调研有任何问题，请用以下邮箱联系我们：
```

I tried the following:

1. Adding a N before the question mark in the param 4
2. Adding "CharacterSet" =>"UTF-8" in the connection params
3. Adding N'' in the variable like this: $mailText = 'N\'CHINESE TEXT\'' and didn't works

But, after all, I tried using a simple sql server query execution:

```
$sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO cat_textocorreo (idTextos, idIdioma, textoCorreo) VALUES (4, 2000,N'".$mail."')";
$stmtCorreo = sqlsrv_query($conexion, $sqlInsert);
if($stmtCorreo){
    echo "YES";
}else{
    if( ($errors = sqlsrv_errors() ) != null) {
        foreach( $errors as $error ) {
            echo "SQLSTATE: ".$error[ 'SQLSTATE']."<br />";
            echo "code: ".$error[ 'code']."<br />";
            echo "message: ".$error[ 'message']."<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

And incredibly it works. Really I don't understand how it works. Some of you can help me?

Note: My database field is in NVARCHAR

I need to insert that chinese symbols because another .NET program will read this text to send an email. And only symbols like that are saved in my database: ¨å¯¹æœ¬æ¬¡è°ƒç ”æœ‰ä»»ä½•é—®é¢˜ï

Comment: Why is the reason unknown? What error is SQL Server yelling at you?

Comment: When you use prepare statement this is not open for sql injection cod. But simple query does. This may be the reason to block the query while using prepare query with prepare statement.

Comment: There's not an error, because it inserts symbols like this ¨å¯¹æœ¬æ¬¡è°ƒç ”æœ‰ä»»ä½•é—®é¢˜ï ... I will explain more in a edit.

Comment: No need to explain, your database charset is wrong so it cannot hold Chinese chars. I do not know enough about SQL Server to have an opinion about NVARCHAR

Comment: And there's a way to insert this using an prepare statement?, because I works with a lot of insertions and this method was the most reliable to manage them.

Comment: Some forums recommends NVARCHAR to store chinese simbols and it works, but the prepare statement replace this characters with rare symbols

Comment: For your fourth param, can you try `CONVERT(NVARCHAR, ?)` instead of `N?`? This post may be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/q/27866090/2191572 with the `iconv()` solution

Comment: I will try using it and report if it works in my code. Thanks

Comment: @JavierJuan Sounds good, let me know. I read up a bit about NVARCHAR and it sounds straightforward but it seems like PHP's SQL Server driver could be buggy. If your SQL Server driver is old then you can entertain the idea of updating it. Would switching to PDO be an option for you?

Comment: Have you considered that the data is being inserted just fine, but that the thing that you're using to _look_ at it afterwards is not treating it as UTF-8?

Comment: @Sammitch Interesting idea. OP Shows two modes of insert so I just took it for granted that the retrieval method and output medium did not change :-/

Comment: I've forced some mojibake that I think approximates how it would display when forced as a single-byte encoding, and it's not far off of the "symbols" OP complains of: https://3v4l.org/ZEi59

Comment: Actually the cp1252 mojibake is spot-on, I just didn't realize OP had chopped their example out of the middle of the string.

Comment: @Sammitch Im using Navicat to see the insert results, and there are a lot of different symbols. And, the .NET app that build the email just read the data like was inserted before, and the test mail sended yesterday shows the same symbols in the field.

Comment: I only posted a little example string, because the full string contains html code. But theres no problem with it. A simple Insert with the text puts the correct symbols in the database, but the prepare statement still changing the chinese characters. The only way that i found is insert the mail body in base64 :S